# Is it safe to add noexec mount option in /dev?

Tags: linux, mount, security, udev

Is it safe to add `noexec` mount option while mounting `devtmpfs` on `/dev`? I am asking this because in my ubuntu machine the default option is `rw,nosuid,realtime` (found using `cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev`). Is there any reason for not adding `noexec` by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No.

There are still programs such as `/sbin/v86d` around, even now, that memory-map `/dev/zero` with `PROT_EXEC`, for no good reason.

## Further reading

- Mikulas Patocka (2019-09-13).  *[`udev` mounts `/dev` with the `noexec` flag](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=940171)*. Debian bug #940171.
- Michal Januszewski (2008-09-21). *[`v86d` segfaults with `-x86emu`, but works if this flag is enabled](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226107#c39)*.  Gentoo bug #226107.

Comment: this is what I am looking for, tnx for your valuable response